# defining the same function but using different operators

Tags: javascript, function, discord.js, operator-keyword

i'm trying to code several similar functions, but use different operators in each. the function below is user.getBalance(), and i'm trying to create functions for, for example, user.getBalance2(), user.getBalance3(), etc. it's extremely repetitive, but i don't know a way to make it more efficient.

is there a way to switch out the operators, or do i have to manually define all the functions like below?

```
module.exports.realGetBalance = (user) => {
  Reflect.defineProperty(user, 'getBalance', {
    value: function getBalance(id) {
        const realUser = user.get(id);
        return realUser ? realUser.balance : 0;
    },
  });
};
```

Comment: Why do you need those multiple functions?

Comment: @LilyO for a discord.js project

Comment: I meant why do you need them in the code. What do they do? How are they different?

Comment: @LilyO they're used to fetch different balances of a user. For example they have 1 of X, and 1 of Y, and 1 of Z; i need a function to fetch each balance individually